# What are the formulae for FVSCHEDULE and ISPMT functions?

Tags: excel

What are the actual formulae behind the **FVSCHEDULE** and **ISPMT** functions in MS Office Excel?
Where can we find reference for that?

Answer (score 1):

Refer:

***FVSCHEDULE*** - https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FVSCHEDULE_function

Formula:
Future value = principal * (1 + interestrate).

***ISPMT*** -
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ISPMT_function